# C++ decltype with auto parameters to forward

Tags: c++, auto, decltype, perfect-forwarding

Just posting here to see if anyone can lend some helpful information in a more ‘laymans’ explanation.

I’ve seen a lot here on stackoverflow regarding the *difference* between decltype and auto. However, I either didn’t click through enough forum posts, or it’s simply not there. This was a test question last week, which I couldn’t figure out for the life of me then, and I’m still super fuzzy on the details now after spending some quality time with Google and other various forums.

**Why is one supposed to use decltype with auto&& parameters to std::forward them?**

What does the pseudo/example code look like for this?

If you know of a similar post here, I’ll happily take the point in the right direction :)

I appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: "Why is one supposed to use decltype with auto&& parameters to std::forward them?" because there is no `T` you could use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

given the lambda function

```
auto f = [](auto&& arg) {
  // ...
};
```

this is roughly equivalent to the template function:

```
template<class Arg>
auto f(Arg&& arg)
{
  // ...
}
```

Note that in them template function we have the template type `Arg` which we can use to forward the argument `arg`

so we could write

```
do_something(std::forward<Arg>(arg));
```

It just so happens that the `decltype(arg)` is `Arg`.

so we can substitute:

```
do_something(std::forward<decltype(arg)>(arg));
```

In the lambda we don't have the template type `Arg`, but the `decltype(arg)` is equivalent.

So again, the same expression serves our our purpose:

```
auto f = [](auto&& arg) {
  do_something(std::forward<decltype(arg)>(arg));
};
```

or we can be a little kinder to the reader:

```
auto f = [](auto&& arg) 
{
  using arg_type = decltype(arg);
  do_something(std::forward<arg_type>(arg));
};
```